# Merge data based on response pattern in R

Tags: r, design-patterns, merge, response

I have a dataframe that has survey response items (scale 1-4). This is what the data looks like for the first 10 respondents:

```
        Q20_1n Q20_3n Q20_5n Q20_7n Q20_9n Q20_11n Q20_13n  Q20_15n  Q20_17n
   1       1      2      1      1      1       1       1       1       1
   2       1      1      1      1      1       1       1       1       1
   3       2      1      1      1      1       1       1       2       2
   4       4      4      2      2      3       3       4       4       3
   5       1      1      1      1      1       1       1       2       1
   6       4      4      4      3      4       4       2       4       4
   7       3      3      4      3      3       3       4       4       3
   8       3      3      2      2      4       2       3       3       2
   9       1      1      1      1      1       1       1       1       1
   10      1      1      1      1      1       1       1       1       1
```

I fit an graded response model to the data, and now have theta hats for each response pattern. There are 901 observations in the raw data, but only 547 observations of theta.hat. The reason is because there is a single theta.hat for each observed response pattern - e.g.,  a score of '1' across all items appears 94 times. The theta.hat dataframe looks like this:

```
      Q20_1n Q20_3n Q20_5n Q20_7n Q20_9n Q20_11n Q20_13n Q20_15n Q20_17n Obs   Theta        
   1       1      1      1      1      1       1       1       1       1  94 -1.307 
   2       1      1      1      1      1       1       1       1       2  10 -.816 
   3       1      1      1      1      1       1       1       1       4   1 -0.750    
   4       1      1      1      1      1       1       1       2       1  22 -.803   
   5       1      1      1      1      1       1       1       2       2   6 -.524
```

What I am trying to do is merge the theta.hats with the original data.  This seems to require matching the response patterns across two datasets.  So, for example, line 10 in the raw data (with all '1's) would receive a theta hat of -1.307 because it matched the response pattern in line 1 of the theta matrix. Both datasets are structured so each variable is a numeric column.

I'm not sure how to send a reproducible dataset for this case, but am happy to if you have suggestions.

Thank you,
Andrea

Comment: Using `data.table` `library(data.table); setkeyv(setDT(df2), names(df1))[df1]`

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple `merge`? Assuming your first dataset (responses) is assigned to `df.1` and the second dataset (modeled with theta) is assigned to `df.2`:

```
merge(df.1, df.2, by = names(df.1), all.x = TRUE)

#    Q20_1n Q20_3n Q20_5n Q20_7n Q20_9n Q20_11n Q20_13n Q20_15n Q20_17n Obs  Theta
# 1       1      1      1      1      1       1       1       1       1  94 -1.307
# 2       1      1      1      1      1       1       1       1       1  94 -1.307
# 3       1      1      1      1      1       1       1       1       1  94 -1.307
# 4       1      1      1      1      1       1       1       2       1  22 -0.803
# 5       1      2      1      1      1       1       1       1       1  NA     NA
# 6       2      1      1      1      1       1       1       2       2  NA     NA
# 7       3      3      2      2      4       2       3       3       2  NA     NA
# 8       3      3      4      3      3       3       4       4       3  NA     NA
# 9       4      4      2      2      3       3       4       4       3  NA     NA
# 10      4      4      4      3      4       4       2       4       4  NA     NA
```

Comment: So simple.  Why didn't I think of that.  I'm trying to take the rocket ship to the store instead of walking, apparently.

Comment: @user1638567 It happens to us all from time to time. Glad I could help.